# Increase the default size of 16kb for adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb, logcat

I have the following code:

```
logcat -f /mnt/sdcard/logcat/logcat.txt -r 1024 -n 10 &
```

Basically what I want to do is print no more then 10 log files, each limited to 1MB.
Now this does print 10 files but each file is no more then 16kb, which is the default limit.

How can I increase the limit to allow me to print 1MB files?